# How can i retrieve the image stored in binary format from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sql-server-2008

I am storing the image in a database and using `c#` as the front end.

I am storing the image by converting into binary format.

How can I retrieve the image stored in binary format from database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC How to display a byte array image from model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952514/mvc-how-to-display-a-byte-array-image-from-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConnectString);
con.Open();
OdbcCommand checkcommand = new OdbcCommand("SELECT contents FROM MyTable WHERE MyClause",  con);
OdbcDataReader checkreader = checkcommand.ExecuteReader();
byte[] array = null;
if (checkreader.Read())
    array = (byte[])checkreader.GetValue(0);
else
{
   //Error
   return false;
}

File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\MyImage.jpeg", array);
```