# show image from byte array ASP.NET without use of Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC. I'm working on an application that either uploads an image or takes screenshots of a webpage after that comparing them to each other. I'm not using any database.

My question is the following: I have an `ActionResult` method that for is taking care of the image upload:

```
public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file, string upload)
{
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        if (String.Equals(upload, "Upload Base Image"))
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, file.FileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            Pic1.UploadedImage = new Bitmap(path);
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            Pic1.ByteImage = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(Pic1.UploadedImage, typeof(byte[]));
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

What I want to do is to display the `Pic1.ByteImage` which is a `byte` array in a view that I wrote. How should I proceed?

Comment: How do you plan on persisting the byte array?  You could use a file system, but what problem did you encounter / what didn't work for you.

Comment: Pic1 is a model (I named it Picture), it has 3 attributes, 2 as Bitmap object and the other is byte[]

Comment: I'm using a global variable in which I store the uploaded image Pic1.ByteImage, I want to use it and to display it in an <img> tag in the view

Comment: May this link can help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952514/mvc-how-to-display-a-byte-array-image-from-model

Comment: Thank you @Tans, I saw this thread before but I'm really stuck on how ,after filling the "Pic1" object with a byte array, can I get this object and use it in the view. 
I'm not using any DB that's why I'm led to store the image in that object