# How to show Image from byte array with FileContentResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts, arrays, system.web

**So lets say I am creating a few charts like so:**

**Controller:**

```
    foreach (var m in model[0].HistoryValues)
    {

        var chart = new Chart(width: 700, height: 600)
        .AddSeries(
        name: m.LastUpdateSTR,
        chartType: "bar",
        xValue: new[] { "Server", "Db", "Tickets" },
        yValues: new[] { m.ServerPerformance, m.Databaseperformance, m.SoldTicketsLastUpdate })
        .GetBytes("jpg");

        m.Bytes = chart;

    };
```

**Now I want to display these charts as images in my view:**

```
@foreach (var t in Model[0].HistoryValues)
{
    <img src="@CalculationHandler.getImage(t.Bytes)" alt="Chart Image" />
}
```

**The getImage method:**

```
public static FileContentResult getImage(byte[] bytes)
{
    return new FileContentResult(bytes, "image/jpg");
}
```

**The result :**

[image]

**Other attempts:**

This gave me a serverError, sadly I do not know why since I could not debug the getImage method when doing this.

```
@foreach (var t in Model[0].HistoryValues)
{
    <img src="@Url.Action("getImage", "OverWatch", new { Mybytes= t.Bytes })" alt="Chart Image" />
}
```

This gave me the same result as the first code in this post but again I could not debug the getImage method,

```
@foreach (var m in Model[0].HistoryValues)
{
  <img src="@Html.Action("getImage", "OverWatch", new { Mybytes= m.Bytes })"    alt="Chart Image" />
}
```

**NOTE:**

I do not want to save any images to the project. This application is intented to be used by multiple users and I do not want to flud it with numerous pictures.

How do I solve this?

EDIT:

When using the write method like so:

**Controller:**

```
    foreach (var m in model[0].HistoryValues)
    {

        Chart chart2 = new Chart(width: 700, height: 600)
        .AddSeries(
        name: m.LastUpdateSTR,
        chartType: "bar",
        xValue: new[] { "Server", "Db", "Tickets" },
        yValues: new[] { m.ServerPerformance, m.Databaseperformance, m.SoldTicketsLastUpdate })
        .Write();


        m.Bytes =chart2.GetBytes("jpg");


    };
```

This shows only one chart , Also my layout does not get displayed when doing this.

EDIT 2:

Tried this:

```
        var chart = new Chart(width: 700, height: 600)
        .AddSeries(
        name: m.LastUpdateSTR,
        chartType: "bar",
        xValue: new[] { "Server", "Db", "Tickets" },
        yValues: new[] { m.ServerPerformance, m.Databaseperformance, m.SoldTicketsLastUpdate })
        .GetBytes("jpg");

        string t = Convert.ToBase64String(chart);
        t = t.Replace('-', '+');
        t = t.Replace('_', '/');

        m.Bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(t);
```

View:

```
    @foreach (var m in Model[0].HistoryValues)
    {
        <img src="@Url.Action("getImage", "OverWatch", new { Mybytes= m.Bytes })" alt="Person Image" />
    }
```

Result.

[image]

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952514/mvc-how-to-display-a-byte-array-image-from-model) may help you

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! vent crazy this weekend and finaly an answer!