# MVC Dynamic Image Loading Whilst Masking Filename

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a set of Images in their own folder in the root of an mvc project and these all correspond to their filenames that are listed in a database. I want to be able to load these images to the page as logo.png everytime regardless of their actual filename. I don't need it to change the filename itself, just to mask it with a temp name of logo.png, therefore staopping people from guessing other logo names in the browser URL. Is there a way to this in MVC?

Comment: Why even use a temp name?  You could turn your images into byte arrays and just bind the <img> tag to to the byte array directly.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952514/mvc-how-to-display-a-byte-array-image-from-model

Comment: The image isn't stored in the DB it's just a string of the filename and extension

Comment: yoiu can read the file into a byte array in your controller action.

Comment: I have absolutley no idea how I'd do that - have you got an example or tutorial you could point me to have a look at? Or is that what the link that you shared above is doing?

Comment: Replace the db calls that are populating the bytearray with calls to 
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("your file path")