# How to display image saved as bytes in database on MVC View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm saving uploaded images to my database by using HttpPostedFileBase as follows:

```
private void Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // save the file to hard drive, we can delete it later
        var FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var FilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Uploads/"), FileName);
        file.SaveAs(FilePath);

        byte[] FileBytes;
        using (var Fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var Reader = new BinaryReader(Fs))
            {
                FileBytes = Reader.ReadBytes((int)Fs.Length);
            }
        }

        OrtundEntities db = new OrtundEntities();
        ImageModel Image = new ImageModel
        {
            Data = FileBytes,
        };
        db.Images.Add(Image);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
    }
}
```

So now I have the file bytes saved in my database.

Clearly I can't use an HTML `<img` tag to display the image so what delivery mechanism should I use here? Should I rather keep the file and store the filepath along with (or in place of) the byte array?

Comment: This has already been asked, you can see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952514/mvc-how-to-display-a-byte-array-image-from-model

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

1. Convert the `byte[]` to Base64 string, here a [sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx) how to convert
2. use `object` tag or `img` to display  the image

Your code should look like:

```
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes); // bytes is the binary  data converted to byte array
```

then in your view

```
<img alt="" src='@(string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}",Model.Base64))'/>
```

or

```
<object data='@(string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}",Model.Base64))'></object>
```

Hope this will help you