# Try pass parameter from view to controller method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mongodb

I have a controller method that returns image from MongoDB, and I want to show it in my view:

```
<HttpPost()>
        Function ShowImage(cardNumber As String) As FileContentResult

            Dim Handler = New MongoDBHandler()
            Dim newString = cardNumber.Replace(vbLf, "").Trim().Replace("""", String.Empty)
            Dim byteArray = Handler.ReadImage(newString)

            Return File(byteArray, "image/png")
        End Function
```

I have the javascript function:

```
function postCardNumber(elm) {
    var CardNumber = $(elm).closest("tr").find(".card-number").html(); 
    var $img = $('<img>');
    $img.attr('src', "data:image;base64," + @Html.Action("ShowImage", "CreditCard", CardNumber));
    $("#myModal").append($img);
}
```

But there is a red underline under "CardNumber" parameter for the `attr` function.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that razor templates works with JavaScript? You can translate your razor syntax to js/HTML. But I'm not sure that its works vice-versa. Razor syntax transpiled when your page rendered by the server,js starts working when page loaded. You should rewrite your code to js without using razor in this way

Comment: so what the solution for passing parameters without razor ?

Comment: Just render your URL and pass it as a strings,then add query params

Comment: didnt understand the solution

Comment: @Html.Action("ShowImage", "CreditCard")  this thing will be rendered to '/CreditCard/ShowImage', third argument  are params passed to query,so you should replace your code to plain string and add params.
Result will be 'CreditCard/ShowIamge/'+CardNumber

Comment: You can help me how replace the returned byteArray instead of CardNumber parameter?

Comment: Actually, i`m not sure,that you should use   "data:image;base64". I think,if you  put URL to your endpoint,browser should handle everything else without you.
In the other side, if you need serverside rendered images,look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952514/mvc-how-to-display-a-byte-array-image-from-model