# why is this image not being displayed in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to display images from the database but it's not working.Can anyone help me out please help is appreciated.
The result is what I get from this code.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <li class="last">
        <a href="#"> <img src="../<%#Eval(" Image") %>" /></a>
    </li>
</ItemTemplate>
```

[image]

table with content:

[image]

Comment: Inspect that element and see what is loaded as `src`

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Have you checked what is the value loaded as src for that image? through inspecting the control from the browser?

Comment: have you tried this: `src='<%# "../" + Eval("Image") %>'`

Comment: What is the value of `Image`? Suggest you refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952514/mvc-how-to-display-a-byte-array-image-from-model)

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by src give an example plase

Comment: please check the images as I have uploaded a pic of value of Image thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot display `byte[]` in `html` tag html does not support this type so you have to convert it from `byte[]` to `Base64String`  like

```
<a href="#"> <img src="data:image;base64,<%# Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Image")) %>" /></a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much mate