# Cannot render byte[] as an Image in MVC 5 ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple MVC 5 app using Northwind database. The view in question is displaying a list of categories from `Categories` table in Northwind. I have tried  to render the byte array using an `img tag` but without success.

I have looked at [MVC How to display a byte array image from model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952514/mvc-how-to-display-a-byte-array-image-from-model) and tried using a custom html helper but even that did not work

Is there something I am missing in my approach when converting a byte[] to an image?

**Tried following** ( look at img tag for what I tried)

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="@String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(item.Picture))" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CategoryID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CategoryID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CategoryID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**EF Category class**

```
public partial class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15)]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "image")]
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
}
```

**Action method**

```
  public class CategoriesController : Controller
  {
        private NorthwindDB db = new NorthwindDB();

        // GET: Categories
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Categories.ToList());
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that it is not easy the convert Nortwind image to format base64 string. I found a [source](https://www.developer.com/net/article.php/3818161/Displaying-and-Customizing-Images-from-a-Database.htm). According to explanation, *"Northwind images were created with Microsoft Access so they have a 78 byte OLE header"*. So, we should remove the headers. Firstly, modify `Category` entity.

```
public partial class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15)]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "image")]
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Base64String
    {
        get
        {
            var base64Str = string.Empty;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int offset = 78;
                ms.Write(Picture, offset, Picture.Length - offset);
                var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
                using (var jpegms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bmp.Save(jpegms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    base64Str = Convert.ToBase64String(jpegms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return base64Str;
        }
    }
}
```

And then put the `Base64String` property inside img attribute.

```
<img src="@String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", item.Base64String)" />
```

Comment: It still does not work after I changed to your format.

Comment: Would you share HTML output ?

Comment: You can see the detailed output in this video: https://www.screencast.com/t/kk7bYdnEpc

Comment: I am using the standard Northwind database which comes pre-populated with data. If you have this database on your computer, then go to Categories table and the last column holds an `Image` data type of column. So, I am not saving any data but just retrieving it.

Comment: So, you are ignoring the first 78  elements of byte[]?

Comment: Yes, otherwise conversion is being failed. I tested, it works.

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks. I also could just use the following html but with an offset of 78: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.Picture,78, item.Picture.Length -78)" />`
`

Comment: But how did you know that offset is 78?

Comment: May be this image column was for Access database when originally created and never got changed when migrated to SQL Server!

Comment: You're welcome. I found a source. https://www.developer.com/net/article.php/3818161/Displaying-and-Customizing-Images-from-a-Database.htm . According to explanation, "Northwind images were created with Microsoft Access so they have a 78 byte OLE header". I removed them.