# Render a view containing hundreds of images

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My viewmodel object contains approximately 200 to 300 objects.

One property for that object is an 100x100px image converted to `Base64string`.

Here is my code for rendering the entire collection:

```
<table class="table-condensed">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var ua in day.Value)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 105px;">
                    <img src="data:image;base64,@ua.UserProfileImage" style="width:100px;height:100px;" alt="User Image" />
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <b>@ua.UserFirstName @ua.UserLastName</b> <a asp-controller="Users" asp-action="File" asp-route-id="@ua.UserId">(Profile)</a><br />
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ua.TeamName))
                    {
                        <small>@ua.TeamName</small><br />
                    }
                    <span class="label label-default">@ua.FunctionName</span><text>&nbsp;</text><span class="label label-default">@ua.HireDate</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

The logic and the time till the controller returns the data is 0.5 seconds so my problem isn't there.

The render speed for the entire view is about 5 to 8 seconds because of those many images.

Is there a way to improve that number?

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.

Comment: The @dav_i solution at this question could help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952514/mvc-how-to-display-a-byte-array-image-from-model

Comment: The solution provided there is for a single image while here i'm dealing with 200+ of them

Comment: Have you optimized the images for bandwidth and set appropriate caching for them?

Comment: I run the default cache configuration with minimum optimization done for the images. I will try to do what you are saying. Can you give me some directions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax javascript to load every image and you can implement some pagination , the load time will be the same but on the client side it looks better

Comment: That's what i end up doing a couple weeks ago but it didn't improved my render speed. I'm searching for a solution to decrease the page load despite using Ajax or the default render engine.

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak it didnt improve your render speed likely because you didnt implement lazy loading correctly.  I guarantee lazy loading would speed up page rendering when done correctly

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use lazy image loading
https://github.com/craigbuckler/progressive-image.js. You can see at demo that images are not loading until you scroll to their destination