# How to Put the image from SQL to page in c#

Tags: c#

I use this at my class

```
  public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
```

And this to my view but

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.EmployeeCollection)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <span alt="image" class="img-lg" >@item.Picture</span>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
             </div>
         </div>
     }
```

but to the image section in the web it doesn't show the image but it only show this
          System.Byte[]

How can i fix this ?

i even try this but its the same

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.EmployeeCollection)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <img alt="image" class="img-lg" src="@item.Picture">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
             </div>
         </div>
     }
```

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952514/mvc-how-to-display-a-byte-array-image-from-model)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done easily with `Convert.ToBase64String()`

```
string Image = "data:Image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Then used like this

```
<img scr="@Image">
```