# upload image and show that in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new to dotnet and asp.net (C #) and want to get the image (s) from users and then show them on the index page. How can I do this?

inside **model.PropertyDetails**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RealEstateSystem.Models
{
    public class PropertyDetails
    {
        public PropertyDetails()
        {

        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ShortDetails { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public byte[] Images { get; set; }
    }
}
```

insede **views.PropertyDetails.(Create.cshtml)**:

```
@model RealEstateSystem.Models.PropertyDetails

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>PropertyDetails</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ShortDetails" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ShortDetails" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ShortDetails" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Images" class="control-label"></label>
                @*<input asp-for="Images" class="form-control" />*@
                <input type="file" accept="image/*" asp-for="Images" class="form-control-file" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Images" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

inside **views.PropertyDetails.(index.cshtml)**:

```
@model IEnumerable<RealEstateSystem.Models.PropertyDetails>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShortDetails)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Images)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShortDetails)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Images)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

inside **Controllers.PropertyDetails**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RealEstateSystem.Data;
using RealEstateSystem.Models;

namespace RealEstateSystem.Controllers
{
    public class PropertyDetailsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public PropertyDetailsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: PropertyDetails
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.PropertyDetails.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: PropertyDetails/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var propertyDetails = await _context.PropertyDetails
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (propertyDetails == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(propertyDetails);
        }

        // GET: PropertyDetails/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: PropertyDetails/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,ShortDetails,Description,Images")] PropertyDetails propertyDetails)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(propertyDetails);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(propertyDetails);
        }

        // GET: PropertyDetails/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var propertyDetails = await _context.PropertyDetails.FindAsync(id);
            if (propertyDetails == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(propertyDetails);
        }

        // POST: PropertyDetails/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,ShortDetails,Description,Images")] PropertyDetails propertyDetails)
        {
            if (id != propertyDetails.ID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(propertyDetails);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!PropertyDetailsExists(propertyDetails.ID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(propertyDetails);
        }

        // GET: PropertyDetails/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var propertyDetails = await _context.PropertyDetails
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (propertyDetails == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(propertyDetails);
        }

        // POST: PropertyDetails/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var propertyDetails = await _context.PropertyDetails.FindAsync(id);
            _context.PropertyDetails.Remove(propertyDetails);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool PropertyDetailsExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.PropertyDetails.Any(e => e.ID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

**this is mysq sql server**:
[image]

I searched the web but did not find any questions like this.
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952514/asp-net-mvc-how-to-display-a-byte-array-image-from-model) ?

Comment: I think this does not work because it shows me when I upload an image (the value 'C: \ Users \ Mohammad Joe ad \ Pictures \ Screenshots \ Screenshot (12) .png' is not valid for images) and when Check the database image is not stored in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net core use **IFormFile** to accept the file,you can check my demo:

The file in database is a string which is the name of the picture in wwwroot, it is
transformed by the Iformfile.

Model:

```
public class PropertyDetails
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ShortDetails { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Images { get; set; }  //to string
}
```

Create action:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,ShortDetails,Description,Images")] PropertyDetails propertyDetails,IFormFile file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string uniqueFileName = null;  //to contain the filename
            if (file!= null)  //handle iformfile
            {
                string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Images");
                uniqueFileName =file.FileName;
                string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
            }
            propertyDetails.Images = uniqueFileName; //fill the image property
            _context.Add(propertyDetails);  //save
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(propertyDetails);
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShortDetails)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="~/Images/@item.Images" height="40" width="40"   
                     asp-append-version="true">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Create.cshtml:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        //....
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Images" class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control-file" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Images" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]